# Using Indexof to check if string contains a character

Tags: c#, printing, contains, indexof

What I'm trying to do is type in random words into box1, click a button and then print all the words that start with "D" in box2. So if I was to type in something like "Carrots Doors Apples Desks Dogs Carpet" and click the button "Doors Desks Dogs" would print in box2.

```
    string s = box1.Text;                
    int i = s.IndexOf("D");
    string e = s.Substring(i);
    box2.Text = (e);
```

when I use this^^
It would print out "Doors Apples Desks Dogs Carpet" instead of just the D's.
NOTE: These words are an example, I could type anything into box1.

Any help?

Comment: No this is not homework, this is me trying to learn C#

Comment: Then it's still an academic project (it's purpose is to teach you, not to solve a problem), which, from our point of view, is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Okay, what a about more that one space? Is this just for captial dees?

Comment: It's just for capital D's. Tim Schmelter's post solved this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify this by using LINQ

```
var allDWords = box1.Text.Split(' ').Where(w => w.StartsWith("D"));
box2.Text = String.Join(" ", allDWords);
```

Comment: Perfect mate. any chance of a little explanation to how this works?

Comment: @user1300788: it takes initial string and split it in words (blank space is separator); from this list it takes only words starting with D and finally join list items in a string using blank space as separator.

Comment: this does exaclty what was asked (no more) and is what I wrote more slowly (+1).

Comment: doesn't deal with other whitespace seperators or lowecase dees but that was not asked for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I agree, very simple with nothing unnecessary (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
box2.Text = String.Join(" ", 
                box1.Text.Split(' ')
                         .Where(p => p.StartsWith("D")));
```

Comment: why " ".ToCharArray() instead of ' '

Answer (score 0):

You can match the `D` words with a regular expression and iterate over the results

Try this regex

```
D\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split up the text into words and then check to see if each word starts with `D`.  When looking for the first character it's easier to just check it directly.

```
string s = box1.Text;  
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var cur in s.Split(new char[] { ' ' })) {
  if (cur.Length > 0 && cur[0] == 'D') {
    builder.Append(cur);
    builder.Append(' ');
  }
}
box2.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is:

Lets suppose,

```
 string str = "Dog Cat Man etc";
            string[] words = str.Split(' ');

            List<string> wordStartWithD = new List<string>();

            foreach (string strTemp in words)
                if (strTemp.StartsWith("D"))
                    wordStartWithD.Add(strTemp);
```

Hope this help.